# Storing additional info along with cv::Mat elements

Tags: c++, opencv

What's the best way to store some additional info along with pixels of image? Right now I'm thinking about something like `vector<vector<vector<Info*>>>` with two first indices indicating corresponding pixel's coordinates. Is there something better?

Answer (score 1):

Most often there is no single "best" solution.

Your vector of vectors seems a bit complicated, but can be good if each coordinate always have a lot of associated information.

If only some of the pixels have additional Info, you can possibly use a more sparse data structure

```
map<coordinates, info>
```

and only store info for a few coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

If your information is not complex (can be described by a up-to-4-channel vector) you could store the information in another cv::Mat with the same size as you image. If the information for each pixel is more complex you could store a pointer in each matrix element:

```
cv::Mat additionalInfo(image.size(), CV_32S); // CV_32S = int (usually the type used for pointers)
additionalInfo.at<CV_32S>(col,row) = new ComplexStruct; // Writing
ComplexStruct* info = additionalInfo.at<CV_32S>(col,row); // Reading
```

Before you try this approach, ensure that:
    sizeof(CV_32S) == sizeof(ComplexStruct*)